# Finding the dimension of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Consider $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n} = \{(k_{1}, k_{2}, ... , k_{n}) : k_{i} \in \{0,1\}$ mod $2\}$. Let $M$ be the subset of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$ given by $k_{1} + k_{2} + \cdots + k_{n} = 0$. Prove that the dim$_{\mathbb{F}}M = n - 1$.

Attempt : By the rank nullity theorem dim$_{\mathbb{F}}\mathbb{F}_{2} +$ dim$_{\mathbb{F}}M =$ dim$_{\mathbb{F}}\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}$. The result easily follows then.

Seems pretty straightforward, however I wanted to see how to prove it by exhibiting a linearly independent list of $n - 1$ vectors of $M$ and prove that it spans $M$. Does anyone know the proof of this that they could show me? The above argument is much more simple but I like to see things at other points of view! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your title is wrong: it is about finding the dimension of a subspace (i.e., $\;M\;$ ), not a field...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following set:

$$\left\{(1,1,0,...,0)\,,\,(1,0,1,0,...,0)\,\ldots,(1,0,...,0,1)\right\}$$

Comment: Mark, there is nothing special bout the field. For any field one can define  a subspace with the same condition. And the basis suggested by DonAntonio will work with changing one $+1$ into a $-1$ in each vector.

Comment: Wait what do you mean by changing one $+1$ into a $-1$?

Comment: @Mark, the basis  I wrote works because your base field has characteristic two and thus $\;1+1=0\;$ . In other characteristics whis wouldn't work, so change the rightmost $\;1$'s to $\;-1\;$ ...